# Deleting Repeating Data Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, bigdata

I have a huge database of meshed flow distrubition along a room. But the problem is the meshes are too small so some part of them is useless and makes computation hard for me. On my y dimension per mesh length is 0.00032. And my y dimension goes from 0 to 0.45. As you can understand there are a lot of useless data.

I want to make per mesh length equal to 0.00128 instead by deleting rows which is not dividable by 0.00128, how to do that ?

```
trainProcessed = trainProcessed[trainProcessed[:,4]%0.00128==0]
```

I have tried this line of code (trainProcessed is my data as a numpy array) but it goes like 0 -> 0.00128 -> 0.00256 -> 0.00512. But there are rows which has the value 0.00384 and that's also dividable by 0.00128. By the way array shape is (888300,8).

Example Data :

> X: [0,0,0,0,0.00031999,0.00031999,0.00063999,0.00064,0.00096,0.00096,0.000128,0.000128]

Example Output:

> X: [0,0,0,0,0.000128,0.000128]

Comment: You need to add a sample data and expected output here. Secondly (0.00385%0.00128) doesn't give a absolute zero...it is close to zero but not exact zero. See if this works 
trainProcessed = trainProcessed[round(trainProcessed[:,4]%0.00128,0)==0.0]

Comment: Added details, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case and the function modulo, i'll use the Decimal:

```
import pandas as pd
from decimal import Decimal
df = pd.DataFrame({'values': [0.00128, 0.00384, 0.367, 0.128, 0.34]})
print(df)

#convert float to str then Decimal and apply the modulo
#keep only rows which are dividable by 0.00128
filter = df.apply(lambda r: Decimal(str(r['values'])) % Decimal('0.00128')  == Decimal('0') ,axis=1)

#if data are smaller you could multiply by power of 10 before modulo
#filter = df.apply(lambda r: Decimal(str(r['values'] * 1000)) % Decimal('0.00128')  == Decimal('0') ,axis=1)
df=df[filter].reset_index(drop=True)

#the line: df=df[~filter].reset_index(drop=True) does the (not filter)
print(df)
```

initial output:

```
    values
0  0.00128
1  0.00384
2  0.36700
3  0.12800
4  0.34000
```

final output

```
    values
0  0.00128
1  0.00384
2  0.12800
```

Comment: This makes all the values equal to zero in my case guess its because the values have more than 5 floating points so they are not exactly dividable with 0.00128 . for ex : i have 0.0038399928829 . I tried rounding them to 5 floating points by turning dataframe to a numpy array, then back to dataframe and applied the filter but that made all the values equal to zero

Comment: the only solution will be to round correctly your data and mulitply all by power of 10 to obtain integer and the modulo will be oka

Comment: if this answer helps you, please, dont forget to uvpvote/validate the answer !!